# Solving a complex inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Disclaimer: The title may be a bit misleading, as the complex numbers aren't ordered. And of course asking if $1+i > 1-i$ would be meaningless, it's only when you consider $|z|$ that an inequality makes sense within complex numbers.

Anyways, im trying to make sense of inequalities with complex valued functions in 4D graphing space. For example,  let $f(x) = x^2+1$, then $f(x) ≥ 2$ results in the solutions $L=(-∞, -1]∪[1, ∞)$. But when solving $f(x) ≤ 0$, we run into a problem, since the function is never less than $0$ within the real numbers,  the solution is no longer an interval on the real numberline. If we are to include complex numbers as the input, we get a meaningless inequality, because as stated before, asking if 1+i is greater than 1-i is meaningless, but if we only consider $|f(x)| ≤ 0$, we get exactly 2 solutions, namely $±i$, since |z| can never be less than $0$, the problem is now an equation, which is easy to solve. But getting to my real question, what is the solution if we consider $|f(z)|>2$ where $z ∈ℂ$? Now, the solution is still not just an interval on the real numberline, as we now have a 2d complex input, but rather a 2 dimensional **area** on the complex plane in 4 dimensional graphing space. And exactly **how** do you specify that area? How do you specify which points on the complex plane will result in a number that when squared and added with one, have an absolute value greater than 2?

To Clarify: whenever you are considering a complex input for a function $f(x)$, the corresponding graph (if you were to graph it like you  graph regular graphs with real inputs), is no longer 2 dimensional. Because when you have a real input $x$, you need 1D for the input and 1D for the output, resulting in 2D graphing space. But when you try to do the same with complex inputs, you actually need 4 dimensions, because then you have a 2D input and a 2D output, namely $2+2=4$ dimensions.

Comment: What is that interval notation you have used for $L$? I have never seen it before, so some context would be helpful.

Comment: Well for some reason, when specifying a set of intervals, or one interval containing the solutions to an inequality, we use that notation. And its very simple, the "$[$" symbol means "From and including", and the symbol "$<$", means "from, but **not** including", and vice versa for their counterparts. 
So the interval $[-1,2>$ would mean "all real numbers from and including negative 1, to, but _not including_ positive 2". And the arrow "$➝$" just means all the way up to infinity, but since infinty isn't a number, we cant actually include it, hence the "$>$" symbol.

Comment: So I am to understand you meant $(-\infty, -1]\cup [1,\infty)$? Who is the "we" that uses left and right arrows for $\pm\infty$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I ment. I believe my notation there may perhaps be a bit unconventional, but thats what I learned from my maths teacher anyways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working over the complex plane, any time you want to grab the modulus of a number you simply need to multiply by the conjugate. In this case we have the function $f(z)=z^2+1$, so we have the following:
$$|f(z)|^2=(z^2+1)(\bar{z}^2+1)=(z\bar{z})^2+z^2+\bar{z}^2+1=|z|^4+2\text{Re}(z^2)+1$$
If you are looking for those complex numbers with $|f(z)|>2$, then equivalently you are looking for those complex numbers with $|f(z)|^2>4$. If we set $z=a+bi$ and substitute into the inequality, we find the following:
$$
(a^2+b^2)^2
+2(a^2-b^2)+1>4$$
Now you can use any graphing utility you want to visualize the region of $\mathbb{C}$ that contains the complex numbers satisfying your inequality, or you can continue your analysis if you want a finer grasp on the relationship between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Good job, this was exactly what i was looking for, but unfortunately, somewhere in your calculations you got some signs mixed, because using CAS (in geogebra), if you expand it you actually get $a^4+2a^2b^2+2a^2+b^4-2b^2+1>4$. If you expand what you came up with, you get $a^4+2a^2b^2-2a^2+b^4+2b^2+1>4$. Whatever you did wrong, you got pretty close xD. (CAS gave me $(a^2-b^2+1)^2+(2ab)^2>4$) But your explanation and answer overall, is still pretty solid.

Comment: @NilsPhillipTalgö I flipped a minus sign; In my first line of math I have $+2\text{Re}(z^2)$, and in my second  line I accidentally wrote $-2\text{Re}(z^2)$. Good catch! I have made the edit to fix the mistake now.